# Sending single mail using mailchimp API V3

Tags: php, email, mailchimp

We need to send single mail using `MailChimp`. Is there any provision in `MailChimp` to send mail without creating list.

According to my understanding we need to :

1. Create campaign
2. create list
3. Map list to campaign

So in case of say `successful registration`, do we need to follow these steps to send single mail or is there some workaround to avoid these many api calls.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Checkout Mandrill, it's an transactional mail sender from MailChimp. I don't think you can do this with MailChimp as it is.

Comment: @Dennis : Okay. I got this link for exact feature difference :http://kb.mailchimp.com/mandrill/mailchimp-vs-mandrill . Thanks for your help

Comment: nice! You're welcome :-)

Answer (score 3):

The Mandrill product (part of MailChimp) is intended for those kinds of one off emails.  They call them "transactional" emails since they are based on the user's action.